# Embed XML Schema in Java application

Tags: java, xml, schema, embed

Is there a way to embed XML Schema in Java application so that it cannot be changed (only used by the application)?

Comment: Changed by who? And what impact would changing this file have on the running of the app (as opposed to say, any other resource file you may have)?

Comment: I have Java application, XML file used by the application and a Schema file for the XML. I want to make sure that the XML is correct. If the 'user' of the app can change the Schema, I have to repeat it's validation logic in the code. This is why I want to somehow isolate it from the XML (not making it available for the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your stated level of requirement it is sufficient to bundle your schema and code together in a JAR. Since the contents cannot be changed by the client (without intent) this fulfills your needs. Now, this doesn't stop anyone from unpacking the archive and running the app manually, but really, you  can't prevent a determined hacker from doing what they will to your binary, once it's out 'in the wild'.

You didn't mention how you are using the XML schema, but it is possible to validate marshall/unmarshall operations against a schema at run time, for most binding frameworks. Read this SO post for a general JAXB example:

[How to validate against schema in JAXB 2.0 without marshalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560422/how-to-validate-against-schema-in-jaxb-2-0-without-marshalling)

Answer (score 1):

You could include a hash of the XML Schema file in your program, and verify that it is correct after loading the file.

Be aware, however, that a resourceful attacker may be able to decompile your program and change the expected hash value to allow for his schema to be loaded. Depends on the environment in which your program will be deployed.