# SAXParseException: value is not a valid value for 'date'

Tags: java, datetime, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I have an object tree of POJOs that represents an XML Schema. This was created with the following `jaxb` ant script.

I want to validate the root POJO and its children entities against the schema for missing attributes.

My code is the following: (try/catch block omitted, inspired by SO question [How to validate against schema in JAXB 2.0 without marshalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560422/how-to-validate-against-schema-in-jaxb-2-0-without-marshalling))

```
public boolean validateAgainstSchema(Pojo pojo)
{
        JAXBContext jc;
        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Pojo.class);
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new ClassPathResource("schema.xsd").getFile());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setSchema(schema);
        marshaller.marshal(schema, new DefaultHandler());
        return true;
}
```

One of my attributes (`pojo.childEntity.someAttribute`) is a `date`

XSD

```
<xsd:attribute name="some_date" use="required">
  <xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:date" />
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:attribute>
```

Java

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "someDate", required = true)
protected XMLGregorianCalendar someDate;
```

It gets populate from a `java.util.Date` object from another POJO (one that is mapped with Hibernate).

```
private static final XMLGregorianCalendar dateToCalendar(Date date)
{
    if (date == null)
        return null;
    try
    {
        GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.setTime(date);

        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                .newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
    }
    catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

The exception is:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '2001-05-11T00:00:00.000+02:00' is not a valid value for 'date'.]
```

This looks like JAXB tries to set both date and time for a field that must carry only the date, and XMLGregorianCalendard is simply a datetime container.

The question is: what causes the error? How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the output for an `XMLGregorianCalendar` property will be based on how you create it.  If you populate the time portion, then the time portion will be output to XML. You can call the `getXMLSchemaType()` method to see what the corresponding XML representation is:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#getXMLSchemaType%28%29

You can use the `@XmlSchemaType` annotation to override the representation.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchemaType.html

**Java Model (Root)**

Below is an object with 3 `XMLGregorianCalendar` fields.  On the 3rd I will use an `@XmlSchemaType` annotation to specify the schema type.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    protected XMLGregorianCalendar default1;

    protected XMLGregorianCalendar default2;

    @XmlSchemaType(name="date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar schemaTypeDate;

}
```

**Demo Code**

In the demo code below we will create 2 instances of `XMLGregorianCalendar`. One will have schema type `date` the other `dateTime`.  By default this is the XML representation used when marshalling to XML.  On the `schemaTypeDate` field we will use the `@XmlSchemaType` annotation to override the default.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.datatype.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        DatatypeFactory df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
        XMLGregorianCalendar date  = df.newXMLGregorianCalendar("2013-07-03");
        XMLGregorianCalendar dateTime = df.newXMLGregorianCalendar("1999-12-31T23:59:00");

        Root root = new Root();
        root.default1 = date;
        root.default2 = dateTime;
        root.schemaTypeDate = dateTime;

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <default1>2013-07-03</default1>
    <default2>1999-12-31T23:59:00</default2>
    <schemaTypeDate>1999-12-31</schemaTypeDate>
</root>
```

---

**UPDATE**

> Ok, since I have loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooots of
>   XmlGregorianCalendars is there a way to tell XJC to add the
>   xmlSchemaType attribute to all XGCs?

JAXB will do this for you when the schema type is one of the build in XML Schema types i.e. `xsd:date` or `xsd:dateTime`, but not when you have extended one of these types.

**XML Schema (schema.xsd)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <complexType name="root">
        <sequence>
            <element name="dateElement" type="date" />
            <element name="dateTimeElement" type="dateTime" />
            <element name="extendedDateElement">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="date" />
                </simpleType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="dateAttribute" type="date" />
        <attribute name="dateTimeAttribute" type="dateTime" />
        <attribute name="extendedDateAttribute">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="date" />
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

**Root**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "root", propOrder = {
    "dateElement",
    "dateTimeElement",
    "extendedDateElement"
})
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateElement;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateTimeElement;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar extendedDateElement;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "dateAttribute")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateAttribute;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "dateTimeAttribute")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateTimeAttribute;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "extendedDateAttribute")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar extendedDateAttribute;

}
```

Comment: The truth is more complex (I thought it didn't matter): I populate the GregCalendar from a Date

Comment: @djechelon - I have updated my answer with information that should help.

Comment: Ok, since I have loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooots of XmlGregorianCalendars is there a way to tell XJC to add the xmlSchemaType attribute to all XGCs?

Comment: @djechelon - The `@XmlSchemaType` annotations should have already been added for you (were they?).  Which implementation and version of JAXB are you using?  If you are using the JAXB in the JDK, which version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: Actually I found that my root entity **was** annotated, but a child of it (throwing the error) was not. I'm looking to confirm whether the XSD is really public so at least I will be able to link it.

Answer (score 1):

If the date is '2001-05-11T00:00:00.000+02:00'  use

```
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:dateTime" />
```

Comment: Sorry. I cannot change the schema. It is a standard schema used in an interoperability process. The schema itself *should* be public but I prefer not disclosing more information about it