# JAXB check if xml is valid for the declared xsd

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I need to know if an xml is valid before calling the unmarshal method of the Unmarshaller.

Now I do this:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("package");

final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
final File xsdFile = new File("pathtoxsd/file.xsd");
final Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(xsdFile);

unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent arg0)
    {
            return false;
    }
});

final File xmlFile = new File("pathtoxml/fileName.xml");

final Object unmarshalled = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
```

But I want to do not be forced to know where is the xsd. The xsd path should be only declared by the xml inside of it and the marshaller should follow the path declared by the xml.

Comment: see my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560422/how-to-validate-against-schema-in-jaxb-2-0-without-marshalling/7575733#7575733

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

1. Parse the XML document with a StAX parser.
2. Advance to the root element.
3. Grab the `schemaLocation` attribute (you may also need to handle the `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute).
4. Grab the path to the XSD from that value (part after the space).
5. Create the `Schema` based on that value.
6. Set the `Schema` on the `Unmarshaller`.

```java
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("src/forum21317146/input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
        xsr.next();

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        String schemaLocation = xsr.getAttributeValue(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI, "schemaLocation");
        if(null != schemaLocation) {
            String xsd = schemaLocation.substring(schemaLocation.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
            SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));
            unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        }

        unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

    }

}
```