# Xml validation against xsd with org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to validate xml against xsd using Jaxb2Marshaller. But i am constantly getting below exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element ""
```

I tried with approaches suggested in the forums but still not working. When i try with simple xml and xsd it works. But when my project specific xml and xsd it fails to work.

Is it a problem with xsd or the way i am loading schemas is wrong?

```
<bean id="reader" class="com.test.batch.CustomizedStaxEventItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="person" />
    <property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters['INFILE']}" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="personUnmarshaller"/>
</bean>
<bean id="personUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.test.batch.Person</value>        
            </list>
    </property>
     <property name="schemas">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:xsd/person.xsd</value>
        </list>
    </property> 
    <property name="validationEventHandler" ref="eventHandler"/> 
</bean>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe the double-dot (`..`) in the `classesToBeBound` value?

Comment: Sorry that is a typo.... It is correct in d code

Comment: Then update the question to match what you actually do.

Comment: Updated d correct code..

Comment: please add more info with your code

Comment: what does your person bean look like?

Comment: You say *"when you try with simple xml and xsd it works"*, which means that spring setup is good. If it fails with more complex xml and xsd, then your xsd is bad, or the xml doesn't fit the xsd. In which case your problem is not with the code shown, but with xml and xsd which is not shown, and there's no way we can help with that.

Comment: Provide xsd and xml at least...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done to validate my xml against an xsd:

[How to validate against schema in JAXB 2.0 without marshalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560422/how-to-validate-against-schema-in-jaxb-2-0-without-marshalling/7575733#7575733)

Comment: sadly i am not supposed to provide xsd and xml as these are project specific... :(:(:(