# CXF Validate Object programmatically for test

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf

I have a WebService implementation using CXF on WilfFly. Schema validation is enabled and working for the deployed web application.

Additionally I have some web service tests using generated classes to call the web service implementation directly. These tests do not use schema validattion as they are not called through cxf but using spring dependency injection.

**Is there a way to programmatically invoke schema validation on a java object using XSD files?**

The problem is that I sometimes have working tests but the same web service operations fail because of marshalling errors at runtime.

If you need any more information or implementation details, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a proper way of validating unmarshalled java object against XSD schema. But you can emulate this, by marshaling the object back to XML and then validating the XML against XSD.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564795/1885467) on how to do it, or an alternative implementation proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13360785/1885467).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that tomorrow :)