# JAXBContext - UnsupportedOperationException for createValidator() method

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-validation

I want to validate a content tree before to marshall it. as per the example of java 1.6 tutorial I've writen the following code to validate the content before the perform the marshalling:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "primer.po" );
PurchaseOrder po = 
  ..... some po valorization
Validator v = jc.createValidator();
boolean valid = v.validateRoot( po );
System.out.println( valid );
```

I don't have error during compilation but a runtime error with:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   **This feature is not available in JAXB RI 2.0**  at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.createValidator(JAXBContextImpl.java:746)

**Does someone knows how to replace the createValidator with JAXB RI 2.0 to have an On-Demand validation on the purchase content tree?**
PS: I'm not looking for a validation during unmarshalling or marshalling but on-demand on po

Comment: What is the point of doing a pre-valiation before the marshalling? Also do you have an XSD or do you just want to check that the XML syntax is valid?

Comment: This is a duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560422/how-to-validate-against-schema-in-jaxb-2-0-without-marshalling.

Comment: Perhaps I have to add some further specification! Having generate the PurchaseOrder from an xsd with jaxb, I would like to validate it without specifying the xsd again (as per the new link you reported!) The new Schema solution requires the xsd file... Is there a way to do it without specifying again the xsd?

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope I Would like to use the implicit xsd used to generate the purchaseOrder classes with jaxb. even if I have the explicit xsd, i have some problem with the proxy in office that doesn't resolve the url included in the xsds... **Is it possibile to achieve the goal without the explicit schema?** Anyhow, without my problem on the proxy the link of duplication is surely a way to perform the validation...